# Lucene not searching for word having '-'

Tags: c#, .net, lucene

I am using Standard Analyzer to store text as well same analyzer for searching

Here is a code for searching text:

```
        Analyzer analyzer = GetAnalyzer();

        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("Text", analyzer);         
        parser.SetAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
        Query query;        

            query = parser.Parse(finalSearch);

        Hits hits = searcher.Search(query);
```

And Here is a code How I am storing Text:

```
fieldText = new Field("Text", text.ToLower(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED);     

document.Add(fieldText);
```

Comment: Please state the issue. Maybe give an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping your characters using `'\'`. `'-'` will be `'\-'`.

From http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters

Lucene supports escaping special characters that are part of the query syntax. The current list special characters are

```
+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \
```

To escape these character use the \ before the character. For example to search for (1+1):2 use the query:

```
\(1\+1\)\:2
```

Comment: I am using QueryParser.Escape("Hello-Break") and it return me "Hello\-Break" but when I do the QueryParser.Parse("Hello\-Break") it remove that backslach...any idea?

Comment: Do you manually enter the second statement in your program? Try QueryParser.Parse(@"Hello\-Break"); to pass a litteral string?

Comment: Still it is not returning any result :(

Comment: Could you post your complete code sample? There is no - in the one you posted in your question.